# Adding another row after where the add function is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this written function :

```
        $(".tdAdd").on("click", function () {
        counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 3; //supposing i only have 2 data
        var count = $("#myTable").length;
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Add" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow); // this is adding row to the end. but i want i on a specific row after where the add button was clicked
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });




});
```

and my table is like this :

```
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
           <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="price1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="ibtnDel"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>        

</table>
```

Here is a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejay/y8F88/)

I want to add another row below where i clicked the Add row button. the fiddle will only add row on the bottom of the table and only the first button will work. any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

i tried :

```
$("table.order-list").eq(count-1).after(newRow)
```

but i still can't get the code to work

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the event listener to the document, because the button is dynamically created. EG:

```
$(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () { ... }
```

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8F88/1/

Comment: Thanks for that!. but how about the insertion of row below where the button was clicked?

Comment: See the fiddle, it adds a new row for each one if you change it like i said.

Comment: but it adds the row on the bottom. i want it below where it was clicked.

Comment: Then use `newRow.insertAfter( $(this).closest("tr") )`, as in this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/rplantiko/cDa3N/

Comment: @rplantiko, im wondering, if i click add button it adds 2 rows instead of 1.. this only happens when i use $(document)on."click",'.tdAdd',function{...}); ( this works even on dynamically created elements) .

but when i use ('.tdAdd').on("click",function{...}); it only produces one row but if i click add on dynamically generated elements it doesn't work..

note: i've been doing this add/delete rows on a `.jsp` loaded in a `div`. i've tried using `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you looked at the forked fiddle? It only adds one row.

Comment: yes @Andrew. `b.jsp` contains the table and i basically call `b.jsp` from `a.jsp` using `.load()` function. i wonder why it doubles the rows added. when i run `b.jsp` only it will only add one row. but if i run `a.jsp` and clicked a button to load `b.jsp` when i click an add row button it produces 2 generated element